# Text to mp3 in VBa

Tags: excel, basic

I'm writing a program in Visual Basic to pronounce aloud the text and save it later. But I do not know why the pronunciation is wrong

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 Dim msg, sapi, FileStream, Path
 msg = "siema"
 Path = "C:\test\test.wav"
 Set FileStream = CreateObject("sapi.SpFileStream")
 Set sapi = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
 FileStream.Open Path, SSFMCreateForWrite, True
 Set sapi.AudioOutputStream = FileStream
 sapi.Speak "hello"  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Error
 FileStream.Close
 Set FileStream = Nothing
 Set sapi = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a **cell:**

```
Sub SayHello()
    [A1] = "Hello"
    [A1].Speak
End Sub
```